# Is SOAP an API?

Tags: rest, api, web-services, soap

Im having trouble understanding if SOAP is considered an API. Many websites compare SOAP and REST, however while REST is always listed as an Web-API, SOAP is always listed as Web-Service.

Also, im unsure if an API and a Web-Api are the same thing, except for one being on the same system  and one being online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST describes a philosophy in API design, or an architectural style, if you wish: HTTP(s) URIs are identified with resources, HTTP(S) methods are identified with actions; the payload is not necessarily defined, but lately usually JSON. For example:

```
GET    http://www.example.com/myService/user              list users
GET    http://www.example.com/myService/user/1            get data on user with ID 1
PUT    http://www.example.com/myService/user              create a new user
DELETE http://www.example.com/myService/user/1            delete the user with ID 1
```

SOAP also describes a style of web service architecture (or rather, Web Service - see below), but with much stricter requirements: both requests and responses are of strictly defined XML dialect. Meanwhile, URIs identify specific services, and are not otherwise semantic. For example, this is what a SOAP request looks like (sent to e.g. `http://www.example.com/myService`):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:x="http://www.example.org">
  <soap:Header>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <x:GetUser>
      <x:UserId>1</m:UserId>
    </x:GetUser>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The term "API" is a bit ambiguous: it principally means the (abstract) definition of ways that a library or a service could be invoked (1), but it is also sometimes used for the implementation of that definition (2), and also for the documentation of that (abstract) definition (3).

> 1. The wuglet service provides a `create` function with one parameter, a name of the wuglet to be created. It returns the ID of the created wuglet.
> 2. There is a bug in the API, the users are reporting they can't make new wuglets.
> 3. How to make a wuglet? Look it up in the API.

"Web Service" is another ambiguous term: it can be any service that is available over the World Wide Web (i.e. using the HTTP(S) protocols); or it can specifically be a W3C Web Service, which is a specific design of a web service (generic) that involves UDDI, WSDL (another two ETLA you don't need to worry about) and - SOAP. W3C Web Services are mostly only used in complex enterprise-level systems like banking; most people will not need to know about them in detail.

Web API is just API that is available over the World Wide Web, or more precisely, over the HTTP(S) protocols. Web Service API is... see previous paragraph: either same as Web API, or API of a specific W3C-style Web Service.